# Python generate all n-permutations of n lists

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I have n lists of different lengths of wich I want to create all possible permutations.

so e.g. if `a=[1,2]` and `b=[3,4,5]` then I would love to obtain `res=[[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5]]`
I've been trying to achieve this using a recursive function, which turned out to be neither very efficient nor very pythonic. 
How would an experienced python programmer tackle the problem?

Comment: For each i from a: for each j from b: add [a, b] to res.

Comment: Do you only need a solution that supports 2 lists, or should it accept any number of them?

Comment: arbitrary many lists. With a known number of lists this would be to easy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two sequences.

This is already available in Python as a library function: [**`itertools.product`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
>>> list(itertools.product(a, b))
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew the answer needed to be simple. I really got stuck in the wrong mindset and have missed that it was a simple cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by product function in itertools,

```
import itertools
a = [1,2]
b = [3, 4, 5]
out = list(itertools.product(a,b))
print out
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

itertools is definitely the way to go but if you don't want to go the easy route.....

```
def print_permutations(lists, perms=[]):
    if not lists:
        print perms
    else:
        current_layer = lists[0]
        remaining_layers = lists[1:]
        for word in current_layer:
            print_permutations(remaining_layers, perms + [word])



l = (('quick', 'lazy'), ('brown', 'black', 'grey'), ('fox', 'dog'))
print_permutations(l)
```